# At what point in life's history was biodiversity at its greatest?

Tags: speciation, life-history, biodiversity

When considering plant & animal species throughout the entire Earth, at what point in life's history was biodiversity at its greatest?

The aforementioned question stems from [this](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2010/aug/16/nature-economic-security) article about extinction rates, and me becoming curious of the period of time where there was the greatest difference between new/current species rates and extinction rates (while favoring new/current species rates).